# Тапочки невелики - можно ли так написать?

Tags: частица-не, предлоги, прилагательными

Тапочки велики. Тапочки большие.

Тапочки не велики. Тапочки не большие.

Можно ли написать: *Тапочки невелики*. Тапочки небольшие.

Answer (score 1):

Ситуация 1. Примеряем тапочки: тапочки велики, тапочки большие. Всё верно, не годятся тапочки, размер не тот.

Ситуация 2. - Мне кажется, что тапочки большие, они тебе велики.- Нет. Тапочки не велики, они не большие, мне как раз.

Ситуация 3. Хорошие тапочки, аккуратные, небольшие, мне нравятся.

Тапочки невелики - к такому написанию ситуацию подобрать трудно. Хотя по отношению к другим предметам слитное написание возможно: Дом невелик (мал), да лежать не велит.

Comment: Тапочки невелики, в сумку поместятся.

Comment: Да, хороший вариант, речь ненадуманная, естественная.